# Spring Boot 401 Unauthorized Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I am new with spring boot, am trying to do an authorized request with postman but i get 401 Unauthorized.
i am trying to store users in a database H2 using jpa with post request that takes a json as body,
i don't know how to explain more so i ll post the code if anyone figure it out.

```
import engine.user.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }



   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
               .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
               .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
               .and()
               .httpBasic();
   }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)
            throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

dependencies

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["src/resources"]

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'

}
```

the usercontroller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import javax.validation.Valid;

public class UserController {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/register", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody  User user) {
        userDetailsService.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bpAo.jpg)

Comment: Can you display the Authorization tab in Postman?

Comment: @HarryCoder https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bpAo.jpg 
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have not set the Authorization header in Postman. You can do that via the Authorization tab. From the drop down select *Basic Auth* and then provide the user credentails of the user trying to perform the action.

[image: Setup Basic Auth]

Notice how Postman automatically adds the Authorization header.

[image: Auth Header]

Finally, on the body tag, add the json request data.

[image: Request Body]

Again, Postman will automatically add the content type header for you.

[image: Content-Type Header]

Now you can fire your post request.

Comment: The problem is that the post request is authorized so doesn't need Authorization header,
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
and i didn 't make any default login

Answer (score 0):

I changed the dependencies i deleted
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

and replaced with

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'

and it worked.